# Google cloud platform : Issue with robots.txt file not updating

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a small php application with robots.txt file. I deploy the application using `gcloud app deploy` command. After sometime, I changed my robots.txt file and again deployed the application using same command. It changed the robots.txt file. After that I didn't change robots.txt file but created many files and uploaded using same command. Now, a very strange thing is happening. the old robot.txt file is coming. and after sometime, the new one comes and after sometime, again the old one. I don't know what is happening.

After that I deleted robot.txt file from **staging..appspot.com** bucket but it sill shows the robots.txt file. 
**.appspot.com** bucket doesn't contain any code. I don't know why.

I am using free credits given by google and it has been only 11 days.

Thank you.

Comment: It might be a caching issue.  Maybe you have to clear your browser cache?

Comment: I already have cleared the cache.